# Delete last child in firebase node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to secure my new firebase database.

My structure:

```
parentNode
-- child1
-- child2
```

I would like to prevent

- deleting ALL children in parentNode (by forgetting to specify $key, writing to /parentNode)

I would like to be able to:

- push a new child to parentNode (writing to /parentNode)
- delete a child by $key (writing to /parentNode/$key)
- delete the LAST child in parentNode by $key (writing to /parentNode/$key, firebase automatically cleans up parentNode because it's emtpy)

My current (very basic...) solution:

```
parentNode: {
  ".write": "newData.exists()",
}
```

This prevents ALL data from being deleted from the parent, but it also prevents deleting the ONLY child because that would mean the parent has no newData left.

Any pointers?

---

SOLUTION:
Frank's answer below is the correct one. I tried this before, but it didn't work, because I did not make a variable out of `childNode` - since I was not planning to use it.

```
"parentNode:" {
  "childNode": { // <-- This was the problem
    ".write": "data.exist() || newData.exists()"
  }
}
```

The correct version:

```
"parentNode:" {
  "$childNode": { // <-- Notice the $
    ".write": "data.exist() || newData.exists()"
  }
}
```

Firebase ended up ignoring my rule because there existed no node with a name 'childNode'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important rule is to always enforce your requirements on the right level. Since your rules seem to apply to child nodes, that's where you should enforce them.

I think you're looking for something like:

```
parentNode: {
  "$childNode": {
      ".write": "data.exists() || newData.exists()",
  }
}
```

So you can write whatever you want, or you can write `null` if there's an existing value there.

Comment: Thanks! I added something to my original question to complete your answer.